# Can I static_assert without providing a real template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
......
private:
    union u_
    {
        struct m_
        {
            int i1;
            int i2;
            int i3;
        } m;
        char data[SIZE]; // convenience buffer for serialization/deserialization;
    } u;
    T container;
......
};
```

To be able to serialize / deserialize an object of MyClass, I use a union to combine my data fields and use the *data* buffer to do it wholesale. I want to make sure that data is big enough for the collection of data members in case someone expand them in the future, so I added this static assert.

```
static_assert(sizeof(MyClass<int>::u_::data) >= sizeof(MyClass<int>::u_::m_));
```

There are two problems with this approach. First, the compiler complains that the union is not public. Secondly this should hold true for any container type T, so I don't want to be specific, but giving int as a dummy type won't work, but I don't want to introduce another type just for the sake of static assert, is there a way to use a dummy type here?

Is there a more elegant solution?

**EDIT**: James, thanks for bringing up portability issues. Endianness and alignment are legit concerns, but in my case, serialization/deserialization happens locally, so it's OK.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a more elegant solution?

Why not just reinterpret the struct as an array of char?

```
struct m_
{
    int i1;
    int i2;
    int i3;
};

// ...
m_ m;
char* data = static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void*>(&m));
```

Any object can safely be reinterpreted as an array of char.  Of course, you still have to worry about alignment, padding, the sizes of your data types, and potential endianness and other representation issues, but presumably you know that since you're writing the serialization implementation.

Comment: That's a very bad idea because of possible padding. Compilers are free to insert bytes between struct members and these are completely undefined on runtime.

Comment: It's a very bad idea to do serialization this way; however, the original code (in the question) has all of the same problems and this is, at least, a slight improvement.

Comment: @axel: true, but this answer is in the same spirit as the original question. Add that the odds of two structs having the same type(ie. layout) but different padding seems pretty slim, at most, to me.

Comment: Could use a `#pragma pack(1)`, no?

Comment: @Axel:  Is that not _exactly_ what I warned about in the last sentence of this answer?  This is not in all cases a "very bad idea" and is sometimes a perfectly acceptable way to move data around, especially if you control both sides of the communication channel.

Comment: @James:  Not if you want to write portable code, no:  pragmas are fundamentally platform-specific.

Comment: @James, thanks for bringing up portability issues. Endianness and alignment are legit concerns, but in my case, serialization/deserialization happens locally, so it's OK.

Answer (score 1):

```
char data[SIZE];
```

Instead of this, you can do this:

```
char data[sizeof(m_)];
```

It'll always satisfy the condition in this `static_assert`:

```
static_assert(sizeof(MyClass<int>::u_::data) >= sizeof(MyClass<int>::u_::m_));
```

Since it'll always satisfy, no matter what, you would **not** even need to write the `static_assert`!

Comment: What you said is true, sir. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the `private` issue you can consider putting `static_assert` somewhere inside the class, like a constructor or a static method for example.